# How to prevent push to master branch using python?

Tags: python, git, githooks

I have written a pre-push hook in python which prevents push to the master branch partially. i.e when in feature branch and given this command `git push origin master`,the files are pushed.

In the below image when the head is in master branch, the push is prevented.
[image: when the user is in master branch, the push is prevented]

But when the head is in feature1 branch, the push to master is not prevented.
[image]

My code so far :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
from subprocess import check_output

branch = check_output(['git', 'symbolic-ref','--short','HEAD']).strip()
print('branch-name:',branch.decode('utf-8')) #this prints the current branch: feature (if in feature) 


if ((branch.decode('utf-8')) != 'master'):
    print('into if clause')
    print('push to remote successful')
    sys.exit(0)

else :
    print('into else clause')
    print('you are not allowed to push to the master branch')
    sys.exit(1)
```

I want to modify the code in such a manner that following commands must not be allowed(irrespective of the branch it is in) : `git push --force origin master` ; `git push --delete origin master` ; `git push origin master` ; `git co master` ; `git push --force origin`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what problem you're having

Comment: I would recommend to use protected branch in GitHub/ GitLab settings to protect your master... as to your code `branch` is head... so you're only checking if you are on master during push... not if you are pushing to master.

Comment: Is there any option to achieve this via script instead of using protected branch option. I think I have found a solution (https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/5718585),but I am not able to understand the code. the above code(the one in the link) if written in python will do the task i think.

Comment: client hook scripts are insufficient, someone could run those commands with `--no-verify`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using free-plan on private repo in Github, you may not be able to use protected branch feature. So you need to block any push / commit from local.
Please keep in mind, it can be bypassed easily with `--no-verify` command.

I recommend you to do it using husky instead of python, since it is way easier I think..

This is what I did to make it work locally and distributed to all repo's members.

First of all, you need to install husky to control pre-commit and pre-push hook.
Then, I made a pre-push bash script and commit it inside the repository. Then call this script from husky pre-push hook with husky parameter.

This is my husky configuration inside `package.json` (you can set separated config if you want)

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "./commands/pre-commit",
        "pre-push": "./commands/pre-push $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN"
    }
},
```

as you can see I have 2 scripts, one for pre-push and one for pre-commit.

And this is my `commands/pre-push` bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "===\n>> Talenavi Pre-push Hook: Checking branch name / Mengecek nama branch..."

BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
PROTECTED_BRANCHES="^(master|develop)"

if [[ $1 != *"$BRANCH"* ]]
then
  echo -e "\n You must use (git push origin $BRANCH) / Anda harus menggunakan (git push origin $BRANCH).\n" && exit 1
fi

if [[ "$BRANCH" =~ $PROTECTED_BRANCHES ]]
then
  echo -e "\n Cannot push to remote $BRANCH branch, please create your own branch and use PR."
  echo -e " Tidak bisa push ke remote branch $BRANCH, silahkan buat branch kamu sendiri dan gunakan pull request.\n" && exit 1
fi

echo -e ">> Finish checking branch name / Selesai mengecek nama branch.\n==="

exit 0
```

The script basically will do 2 things:

- This script will block anybody who tries to push to a certain branch (in my case I don't want anybody -including myself- to push directly to `master` and `develop` branch). They need to work in their own branch and then create a pull request.
- This script will block anybody who tries to push to a branch that is different from their current active branch. For example you are in branch `fix/someissue` but then you mistakenly type `git push origin master`.

For more detailed instructions you can follow from this article:
https://github.com/talenavi/husky-precommit-prepush-githooks